# Why is my transistor not working?

Tags: arduino, transistors

I drew up this very crude diagram of the way I have this transistor working. I am sending 5v to the base using an Arduino but the LED's will not light up. They do light up a little when I touch with my finger anywhere on uninsulated wire though. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

[image]

Comment: You probably want to move the emitter resistors to the collector, in series with the LED's. Best is one resistor for each LED. Order magnitude 400 ohms each.

Comment: Did it and same results. The base is getting 5v but LED's will not turn on.

Comment: Oh, and label the transistor terminals, and let us know what kind of transistor.

Comment: @MichaelRader You may think the following is rude and you may not. If you do, look at every thing I write and see if it is correct. You not only CAN do much better than you did but you MUST if you want people to understand your questions and if you want to understand their answers.  Yes, you should be sorry - from the diagram you drew how would you expect anyone could understand anything? Andy's diagram is no more "complex" than yours - NOT AT ALL. The difference is that you are drawing low content rubbish instead of trying to learn the absolute minimum necessary to convey the ...

Comment: ... information required.  If you look at **ANY** internet or textbook or magazine circuit every one uses standard symbols for transistors. They do not just have 3 wires coming out they have labels of=r symbols that show what each is. If YOU do not understand the proper symbols and use them then you also cannot connect the circuit reliably. And there are several types of transistor. If you do not know how to tell people what you are using you cannot be sure of connecting them correctly of of having the correct sort. In your Symet question you had type labelled transistors and knew CBE ...

Comment: wow, ok thanks. I was very frustrated and thought this might get my question across as quickly as possible. Next time I'll think it through.

Comment: ... connections. And you could trivially easily (unless there are very special things we don't know) have drawn a diagram of similar quality to your Symet one. That was not marvellous (not your fault) but this one is shocking. Dan Laks answered your Symet quesrion with an excellent diagram icnlided. If you had worked on understandiung his answer you would now understand how transistors work, know what the symbols meant and probably have been able to know what you were doing wrong here. This APPEARS to be gross laziness and unwillingness on your part to make good use of the information...

Comment: ... people have spent time given you. **BUT** / Sorry if that comes across a bit hard, but it may help reset your expectations of yourself. You are keen and trying and able to learn. If you can survive a bit of yelling at by an old guy occasionally and learn from it you'll very probably do well.

Comment: <Grumpy_curmudgeon_mode = off>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have two connections to the circuit. I'd recommend that you connect 0V from the Arduino to the negative end of the battery for this to work correctly.

Assumption: NPN transistor with collector going to LED and emitter resistance a couple of hundred ohms.

A decent circuit diagram would have helped. Note also that having two LEDs in parallel is not a good technique. A better ploy for driving LEDs is to connect emitter directly to 0V and put a current limiting resistor in the collector with each LED.

Here is a picture of what I mean: -

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but from the diagram I drew how would you expect I could understand this complex one?

Comment: However it did work when I connected another ground wire for some reason. Sheesh I have no idea why that worked. But thanks!

Comment: Do you think you could help me solve this issue in the arduino forum? http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/12418/light-sensor-acting-up-when-used-with-other-code

Comment: It worked because to turn on the led requires current flowing into the transistor base. To push current you need a return path hence the 0 volt connection.